# color of linear layout influenced by color of underlaying linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, colors

i included some linearlayouts in a linear layout. But i want the linear layout on top (the included one) to be greyish, and just the background orange. When i try this, everything is orange! Is there some way i can prevent this?

my ll:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/orange">

     <include
            android:id="@+id/bt_overview_list_places"
            layout="@layout/single_overview_item" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
      <include
            android:id="@+id/bt_overview_list_agenda"
            layout="@layout/single_overview_item" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
       <include
            android:id="@+id/bt_overview_list_shopping"
            layout="@layout/single_overview_item" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/bt_overview_list_food"
            layout="@layout/single_overview_item" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

the one i include:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/lloverview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@color/custom_button_grey"
  >
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  >
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/ivoverviewimage"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="225dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvoverviewname"
      android:layout_width="225dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left|top"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
      android:text="naam"
      android:textSize="16dip" 
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"
      android:textColor="@color/black"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvoverviewtext"
     android:layout_width="225dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
     android:maxLines="3"
     android:text="tip"
     android:textSize="12dip" 
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:textColor="@color/black"/>

 </LinearLayout>



 <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/arrow"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:src="@drawable/iconarrowsmall"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_margin="2dip"
     />

</LinearLayout>
<ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/bottom_border"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/custombuttonlist_bottomborder"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

I already tried giving the linear layouts colors programmatically:

```
lPlaces= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bt_overview_list_places);
llPlaces.setBackgroundColor(R.color.custom_button_grey);
```

but everything just stays orange (with some difference in color).

I checked my color, and i think it should be 100% NOT transparent:

```
<color name="custom_button_grey_text">#585850</color>
```

even with the FF added in front of it:

```
 <color name="custom_button_grey_text">#FF585850</color>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i get it:

i created an drawable file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/list_even" />
    <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/list_even" />
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/list_even" />
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_odd" /> 
</selector>
```

(now i have nice colorchange when i press it too)
and set that as background resource:

> llPlaces.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.overview_background_color_even);

Answer (score 0):

try like this in xml

```
android:background="#FF4500"
```

in place of

```
android:background="@color/custom_button_grey"
```

Comment: i don't want that because I hate it when you want to change a color you can't do it in your color value file

Answer (score 0):

You should *override* the background parameter for each included layout. You can override any attribute using `android:layout_*`

Take a look at the official documentation using [`<include>`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include) tag.

Comment: but background color is no layout tag, so that doesn't work. I do this for the layout_width etc, but you can't do that for background (color)